# Minimum number of axioms for a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Usually a $\sigma$-algebra is defined as:

**Def.** A family $\mathcal F$ of subsets of $\Omega$ is said to be a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ if:

(A.1) $\ \Omega\in\mathcal F$

(A.2) $\ A\in\mathcal F\implies\ A^c\in\mathcal F$

(A.3) $\ A_1,A_2,...\in\mathcal F\implies\bigcup _{i=1}^\infty A_i \in\mathcal F$

I fail to see the need of the first axiom (A.1) because the other two seem to immediately imply the first: $\Omega = A\cup A^c \in\mathcal F$.

What's wrong here?

Comment: This is to make sure that $\mathcal{F}$ is non-empty. If it were empty there would be no $A$ to "use" to put $\Omega$ in $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: You could weaken $(A.1)$ by requiring $\mathcal{F} \neq \emptyset$ instead though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But that assumes that $\mathcal{F}$ is nonempty. In your version, the empty set is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 3):

$\emptyset$ satisfies $A2$ and $A3$, but not $A1$.